# Statistical error in a regression

Tags: statistics, error-analysis

I measured some voltage values ($x$) and some corresponding frequencies ($y$). I know that the voltage can only be measured within an uncertainty $\Delta x$. And the uncertainty of $y$ shall be $\Delta y$.

Now I'm interested in the slope of the regression line and analyze it using root (the statistics tool). I used $x$- and $y$ error bars. Root returns an Error on the slope ($\chi^2$-Method).

Is this the final error on the slope or do I have to make some further propagation of errors?

Comment: Perhaps http://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be a better home?

Comment: did not know about this one - good idea, if a mod could move it… :-)

Comment: paging the Reverend Bayes ... call for you on line 1

Comment: somehow I'm not able to directly apply the Bayes' Theorem in this case, perhaps you might give me a hint :-)

Comment: This would be better on [Stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) if you are primarily asking about the method or on [SciComp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) if you are primarily asking about the tool. Let me know which you prefer and I'll ask the mods if they want it (Stats in particular may already have a version...).

Comment: the question would be "does the tool (root) return the total error?". On the one hand it's a question on the tool ("does root do it correctly?"), on the other hand it's a question about the method ("if the regression is done correctly, is it the total error, which is returned?").
I think it would fit very well in Stats…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you mean [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/),<sup>1</sup> and that you fit to a `TGraphErrors`, then you are done.

---

<sup>1</sup> First time I've heard it described as "a statistics tool" though it will do a passable job in that context.

Comment: yep, I meant that root and that TGraphErrors-Class :-)